# How to have notes stay where they are suppoed to be

Tags: plantuml

[This](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/duml/XL31hjem43opNx5w9n2A4HmHZP2GUks1_e1nDeaLnqRska0f_rwdO9gcgdgpPsTcPsSVM7gElO5MLuJKd_c6ajdhKsGA43fjpzBB7gNtxlArrQgp509kHgEJL5tZNRJLmHddaRsq8Ot8yeXLKIsZuS_Eyb5_9rnl09IHoUkG8Beotc5MX2HcQcumMmRYu-itp_0YuPKxkfwurRQPB-01O1qJ6gePNPtDjjiH3R9Sq9LKP4ewiXKEGW2T1BwMYZ2l6v8iCxMIB7-joJ5TuOlopNqVOJHPdeHvWO4zVa9B5nmYPMKAePwMOdBgxy6VjwvMA8G0norbmo_3-p-E0_yVdkCUdc6nY4MPMmGuIzN9Xl0Z8SeJlqlI53vmjrFE65AidGrbEVJsR2EpSuRrC9fqYdVtZRpN5JrWzdWrF569A7wCkiuPXHVbtpi0zkcQs9kV) is the code I want to update. There is a note on the left side of class `Client`. After I added a prototype to an arrow that points from class `Client` to class `ConcreteStrategy1`, the diagram became [this](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/duml/XL31hjem43opNx5wfuTGZE28Q8I4r6iFz0UCiqciE3QoDmLA-VVQJKtJgDMxsRipipDp22mz3xs1LbU4r5_uZfBPw_F0521qsbwabprAxztrQwjLPoa4t4vMPwcwnhl1LaTdd4VsqeQu8iiJL4Mr70n_TfPF-ZlXPWkWZ8nQnpYY6-C35aM8PARc3ejL83xz_htdyJBEAtToFN6hRVE-X2U0TKneg6PqTHRRxIOmo7H1Dr8nMEIHhJ0H0NGa-5egmdmkELbbQ2LP_ZgJRRh25-KB-mfXTCmxDpCEutdyX9Qkc2nbPZIXHaanY_fdyNVMzHg54E2ufIpu9Rq_K4pu_sXEUnZDOZ4KPMuHu29L9nl2jpXHdlXLagRmXlkzSiQGOkriAClKszX6HcSFcxIQTOeFzusyrnKzOV4S6vwpn21-JBhE7eKNvJzkx98XJ_5NbW2766tepKy0) where the note is on the right side of `Client`. How to have the note stay where it was? Thanks.

Comment: Layout can be very frustrating sometimes. How about [this](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/duml/XL71Zjem43qpNp7QqwvMyMhtY6Y45Ab7Ug0_O9n9Ok7Oo1uNAENVQvUOfgXLR_7CUs_UUra7bfxZQ63GBI6D1pwZPFPw5va2XBss1-dbYD9xT_mwQBMt509-p5OxgVQzTz6sZJFE8tjfGrgHvHcgfKv6mv-TvQt-JlZ-0Q2CJ5fD6j69yGABAYGoKt-6nMiWtawlvp9-IVFMRTr8F6ZRFx_05S0w9ZJKCRgkY2sNCnWKkg0JgSYKU6HRp4G0dGY-augmdCjENWkqbIn_dIasNUMh-ewzXp2QB4zcPC1Daw_Y9xHqnEoa4D9jTLCI3mb_B_wC-FQ6GWXmF50H_9A__wEOyV_GdCU_6SSgLdKf3-2GVgdi2P_IH7dYUpUQmXEkLiePGugriw6kSrrJ2HEwU7ZFguSgyUA-aVUwfIiihbEn3omHnOzPnSMZyAB-ourbDkGflUeQDWrM5Ku4MAUSSJG_0G00)?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Have tried. It takes up too much space and is ugly. Look at that long and useless something between the note and the class. Agree! It's very frustrating.

Comment: [Here](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/duml/XL0zRzim49rzl-AGAK4W1ibef4800ntRmTsA3WnvaWXHf44UcwIk_tl9sbHLkqKsykvzl7jFaMNWD5aOZ2QaQSTlA9c3UKvC4U9et4u6EQ4CmRzy6OmQ7SM83ulLirHZ7tnoUkEj3yX1kfXNv7Y1qjJ9PFcZTxmrFmZl7m2KbLbhaqVqohY7LHCpcQb_WzLj9DwUVjTrV9Fdsc_zH3mOrr_Vm070UIQqr37whegjrmiOLBgWLrA9AVF8QIn409C9ePEAiDgL9BSLgYNBtpOrfcz2qyxO-GXhoF4fZ8puQLDSyGCwUi6If1AojpegYRCB_op-Fl7k3eKGu7cWAlYvlDzHBFZ_Q2xFFmP7eKN9NBzDQjhQ9Uoa6cLFU9K7AX3FJHcAL_ZugBorfDXu5zksb7UifA9helkoEYiMz_uxXM0q7M1rA3LViaGIFvU5ryHV1wCrkM-YlRIQGU5VMroNr87ohstXYPnEa_q5) the note is below.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator [This one](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/duml/XL11Rjim43oRhrZab22G4lTef4A00BtsuDwA7XXoR16cTWLorSHD_VTATUdARelUo9tPcTbvp6gJ3bqqRV0WTBtkoQgcy3meiicxmBrDjYERahnyQeFRCNAcTpFesRhTDid0_acY9D9aEOyGM6SiZuqTeduGrdNu1bhE9M9WwBu7IT9MPW2BHqPFo_jxOroqe_MJiE9LwSqiggp9AhPxixZDqFMlttKPtunpBslfe6tWxVMDEHZ3eg28ZP9iYjXgDQEPibxZ5MvGZ7jWJzEYCO4LQMCTgDXDIMuBrLkrFsrAJAbIrPoufoDY0Ejvc38SxUazCLveYbGsnn3kA5bVdFeREB_rxexgkZQYBOhWn-dz7yM9_o_DMG_7i5GDLLDQDAQtRcUteAjnuXBqL590lgA71oSnmcaGpaqpzNPiex1BXkK4NNHAR_8LAGMFWraSZWrVRjL3_NtMTSbOVsw3z-0lTVEdrOcK_eRIQagTCFwQnfX7i1-w-0C0) is based on your code. Thanks :)